# Como abrir uma página em nova aba sem sair da página atual

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

O que quero é algo que funcione como o `target="_blank"`, mas não quero sair da página onde o link foi clicado.

Ou seja, ao clicar no link, aparentemente nada mudaria, mantendo a visualização da página atual, no entanto, uma nova aba seria aberta.

Qual código poderia utilizar para fazer isso?

Answer (score 4):

**Nova aba x Nova janela**

Primeiro, só para esclarecer: sobre abrir numa "nova aba". Caso, você queira que abra *somente* numa "nova aba" e não numa "nova janela", isso não é atualmente possível. O CSS3 define a propriedade [`target-new`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/#target-new) para lidar com isso, mas ela não foi implementada em nenhum navegador até agora.

Ok, agora sobre o tema principal:

**Abrir link em segundo plano**

Você pode fazer um [*workaround*](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/workaround) emulando `Ctrl`+`Click`:

```html
<a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40573" id="link">Link para esta questão</a>
<button onclick="simulateClick(true, false, false);">Simulate Ctrl+Click</button>
```

```js
var simulateClick = function (ctrl, shift, isMiddle) {
    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ctrl, false, shift, false, isMiddle ? 1 : 0, null );
    document.getElementById('link').dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

[Ver um jsFiddle semelhante](http://jsfiddle.net/LRc7Z/)

**Porém,**

Esse é um **comportamento do navegador**, **configurado pelo usuário**. E *deveria* ser assim e somente assim. Com razão, não queremos abrir possibilidade abrir links em segundo plano sem notarmos enquanto navegamos pela web! Isso é uma opção do usuário!

Mais do que isso, até o `target="blank"` só encontra respaldo em certas ocasiões: quando o usuário tem algo em andamento que não deve ser perdido com um redirecionamento local de página. Um link aberto enquanto está tocando um vídeo, ou um rascunho não salvo de um e-mail num cliente de emails web.

A ideia de tudo isso é que não devemos alterar o comportamento natural do navegador. Se o usuário quiser abrir o link na própria janela, deixe. Se ele quiser abrir em outra, deixe. Se ele quiser abrir numa aba em segundo plano, deixe. Mas se ele quiser abrir em primeiro, também deixe.

O foco da aplicação web sobre isso deve ser em fornecer a melhor experiência para usuário através de um bom layout e um bom fluxo, sem limitar o usuário a escolhas que ele pode em outra aplicação. Essa abordagem pode até irritar o usuário.

Answer (score 1):

Vai precisar de uma código como este:

```
function openNewBackgroundTab(){
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = window.location.pathname;
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    //the tenth parameter of initMouseEvent sets ctrl key
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                true, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
if(!is_chrome)
{
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
} 
else 
{
    openNewBackgroundTab();
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22858261/194717