# Como abrir uma nova aba em background e redirecionar a aba atual?

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria que ao clicar no link abrisse uma nova aba (mas em background - quero que a aba em foco continue a mesma) e que a aba atual seja redirecionada.

Isto é possível?

Com o código abaixo, é aberta uma nova aba apenas e o foco é alterado para ela.

```html
<a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Visite o Stackoverflow!</a>
```

Comment: Tem como descrever o objetivo? Não está muito claro porque abrir uma outra página sem direcionar o usuário. Por quê o usuário iria clicar em um link assim?

Comment: Parece o procedimento que esses sites de anúncios chatos fazem, clica pra ver o vídeo e abre 500 páginas no fundo.

Comment: @Knautiluz, isso :) kkk

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63180/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-david).

Comment: Agora deu pra entender (acho). Você não tem controle sobre isso, quem decide se a nova aba vai abrir em background ou não é o navegador e as configurações do usuário.

Comment: Então, @bfavaretto, os sites de conteúdo adulto fazem isso, então acredito que seja possível, acho

Comment: Eles mandam abrir novas janelas, mas o navegador define se vai abrir como janela, como aba, e se vai dar o foco ou manter em background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente não é possível abrir uma aba em background, encontrei esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22858261/1518921), o teste:

```js
function openNewBackgroundTab(url)
{
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");

    //the tenth parameter of initMouseEvent sets ctrl key
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                true, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com" onclick="openNewBackgroundTab('https://www.google.com.br');">Redireiciona para a Home</a>
```

No entanto **não funcionou**, creio que o Chrome tenha removido esta capacidade.

Acho que não seja possível de forma alguma fazer isto, porque isso seria controlar a máquina/decisão do usuário final e realmente coloque-se no lugar dele, você gostaria que fosse aberto?

O controle de onde a página será aberta deve ser decisão do usuário creio eu, talvez deva mudar a abordagem.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer isso usando o javascript:

## Abrir duas abas separadas

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="abrir_pagina();">Abre duas páginas</a>
```

JS:

```
function abrir_pagina() {        
    window.open('http://google.com');
    window.open('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/');
}
```

### Abrir uma na mesma aba e outra externa

HTML:

```
<a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/" onclick="abrir_pagina();">Abre duas páginas</a>
```

JS:

```
function abrir_pagina() {        
    window.open('http://google.com');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

É bem simples, é só adicionar o Javascript:

```
    <a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" onclick = "window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';">Visite o Stackoverflow!</a>
```

funcionou, uma abre na outra página e a outra atualiza.

Bom pra fazer o que deseja existe algumas possibilidade.
Recomendo ver [Como abrir uma página em nova aba sem sair da página atual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40573/como-abrir-uma-p%C3%A1gina-em-nova-aba-sem-sair-da-p%C3%A1gina-atual).

Mas note que isso vai depender do navegador e que isso pode ser interpretado como pratica de desrespeito ao usuário do site.

Comment: Quase isso, mas não queria que a página que fosse aberta o navegador me redirecionasse, queria continuar na página que estava, e digamos, so abrir a outra página em outra guia ou nova janela, se é que me entende :)

Comment: Mas @David, na pergunta você disse que queria abrir duas URLs!

Comment: @bfavaretto, concordo, mas queria que fizesse isso tbm, edito a pergunta?

Comment: Eu entendi o que vc quer. Vc quer simular o ctrl + click. fica na aba atual e abre outra sem mudar de aba.

Comment: Tá confuso, as duas coisas ao mesmo tempo não dá. Ou você quer abrir um endereço ou dois...

Comment: issooooo @Bruno

Comment: @bfavaretto, 2 endereços

Comment: Eu atualizei a resposta, tem um link que vai te ajudar.

Comment: Exatamente isso @Bruno, obrigado.

Comment: Tranquilo cara, fico feliz de ter ajudado.

Comment: Mas o que mudou na solução dele de quando era "quase isso" pra agora que é "exatamente isso", @David?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta esse código:

```
$('a.seulink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location= 'http://pagina1.com';
    window.open('http://pagina2.com');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Algo como:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="meusSites" data-site1="http://google.com" data-site2="http://youtube.com">2 url</a>
```

E o js:

```
$('.meusSites').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
window.open($(this).data('site1'));
location.href=$(this).data('site2')
});
```

Comment: Não funcionou :/